# Insert line break for a specific character within a cell every time it is repeated

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a cell that look like below. There is a line break between each line.

```
[User.x]: Bill
[User.xxxxx]: Johnathan
[User.xxx]: Erica
```

The amount of users within each cell varies from cell to cell as well as their names.
I need to insert a second line break between each line to produce

```
[User.x]: Bill

[User.xxxxx]: Johnathan

[User.xxx]: Erica
```

so that it is all within the same cell. This needs to be done for the sake of readability. 
I have tried to come up with a formula that triggers every time it sees '[User.' , but the problem I am having is it only triggers on the first case. Not the second and third case. Any tips or ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace each single hard return with a pair of hard returns:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),CHAR(10) & CHAR(10))
```

[image]